# Searching HP-Trim / Records-Manager using SDK

Tags: sdk, hp-trim

Using the HP-Trim SDK, how do you search for a document by its reference number?

The alleged [documentation](http://www.trimuser.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/TRIM7.0.2_.NETSDK.pdf) refers to methods for straightforward searches:

```
SelectByPrefix
SelectFavorites
SelectByUserLabel
SelectNone
SelectAll
SelectByUris
SelectTopLevels
SelectThoseWithin
```

and a generic search:

```
records.SetSearchString(“createdOn:this week and assignee:me”);
```

but all I want to do is find a document by its index.

These don't work:

```
records.SetSearchString("recordNum: <RecordNumber>");
records.SetSearchString("recordNumber: <RecordNumber>");
records.SetSearchString("reference: <RecordNumber>");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the .NET SDK? If so you can grab a record by its record number like so (C# example):

```
using (Database db = new Database()) {
    db.Connect();
    Record record = new Record(db, "123456"); // Replace with record number

    // Do stuff with record
    Console.WriteLine(record.Title);
}
```

You aren't required to construct a 'formal search' as such.

Comment: I wish i had known about this three projects ago... Curse you, TRIM's documentation!!!!

Comment: Good if the record exists.  Returns "Could not find the Record matching the value '123456" if it doesn't.  Try trimMainObjectSearch.SetSearchString($"number:{the_recordnumber}").

Answer (score 2):

In case you're curious about the correct string search syntax, this would have worked:

```
records.SetSearchString("number: <RecordNumber>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the COM SDK;

```
using (Database db = new Database()) {
    db.Connect();

    Records records = db.MakeRecords();
    records.SelectAll();

    records.FilterString = "number:<RecordNumber>";

    if (records == null || records.Count.Equals(0))
       return;

    Record existing = records.Item(0);
}
```